# How can I return component and custom code in If condition in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pwa-studio

```
import { fullPageLoadingIndicator } from '../LoadingIndicator';
if (placeOrderLoading){
      return fullPageLoadingIndicator;
}
```

I want to add this in the return as well

```
window.scrollTo({
     top: 0,
     behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

for example this is what I want to return window scroll as well with the loading indicator which is component.

```
if (placeOrderLoading){
      return {
          window.scrollTo({
            top: 0,
            behavior: 'smooth'
          });
         fullPageLoadingIndicator
      };
}
```

Comment: what is that you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want a window scroll in the return as well with the fullPageLoadingIndicator

Comment: `in the return` ? not sure

Comment: @KcH yes I want in the return

Comment: This XY problem doesn't make sense: what are you trying to do when returning the window scroll? Do you mean you want to scroll when it is mounted?

Comment: No you do not want to return that, what you are trying to achieve is a side effect. Use an effect in your component for that

Comment: @Terry Below you can check answer someone reply this is what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the component in the return, and if it's a component try:

```
if (placeOrderLoading){
      window.scrollTo({
            top: 0,
            behavior: 'smooth'
          });
      return <fullPageLoadingIndicator />;
}
```

Comment: This side effect should probably be wrapped in a `useEffect` hook, if you're using a functional component.

Comment: @Terry thank you so much it improve my code